# Remote debugging Chrome on Android while offline

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I'm on a plane or do not have connectivity, [remote debugging Chrome on Android](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) fails with a blank window. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you remote debug, Chrome need a version of devtools that matches your mobile browser version. So it loads that specific version off the network. Once they are downloaded, they are kept in AppCache, so you only need to have network available once.

So as long as you start debugging a device (that particular Chrome version) once while you're online, you should then have all those files available later when you're offline.

But there's another workaround to avoid downloading the devtools version:

1. follow the instructions of https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy down to (and including) the `adb forward tcp:9222 ...` section.
2. open http://localhost:9222/json/list (on your desktop)
3. find the tab you care about and copy the `webSocketDebuggerUrl` of it
4. `wsurl = webSocketDebuggerUrl.replace('ws://','')`
5. open this URL (on your desktop):
   `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=${wsurl}`

This will use your desktop's locally installed version of DevTools to inspect the phone. There is a possibility of a compatibility problem, but hopefully it should be small.